# Pointer to member function

Tags: c++, function, member

```
I have the following class:

class Point2D
{
    protected:

            double x;
            double y;
    public:
            double getX() const {return this->x;}
            double getY() const {return this->y;}
   ...
```

};

Sometimes I need to return x coordinate, sometimes y coordinate, so I am using pointer to the member function getX(), getY(). But I am not able tu return coordinate, see below, please.

```
double ( Point2D :: *getCoord) () const;

class Process
{
   ......
   public processPoint(const Point2D *point)
   {

      //Initialize pointer
      if (condition)
      {
         getCoord = &Point2D::getX;
      }
      else
      {
         getCoord = &Point2D::getY;
      }

      //Get coordinate
      double coord = point->( *getCoordinate ) (); //Compiler error

   }

}
```

Thanks for your help.

Comment: for slightly more complex situations, I would use states (state pattern), but for this, it seems okay (now that James has given the solution)

Answer (score 6):

You need to use the `->*` operator to call a member function via a pointer:

```
(point->*getCoordinate)();
```